# How to modify two variables in one 'select' column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a characterization of what I want to do.  In human terms: When rank=2 in my source table (my_table) I want my column called rank2 to increment up (++) and I want another column to increment down (--).  Specifically, I want the rank1 column to increment down one.

```
set @rank1         = 0 ;
set @rank2         = 0 ;
--  ...

SELECT 
create_date,
if(rank=1,@rank1:= @rank1+1,@rank1) rank1,
if(rank=2,(@rank2:=@rank2+1 and @rank1:=@rank1-1),@rank2) rank2
from my_table;
```

The columns I care about in my_table are

```
create_date datetime, 
rank int
```

If it matters, my select statement is going to create several more 'rank' columns (rank3, rank4, etc.) -- I leave it out for simplicity.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.  Your code also seems to have little to do with your description.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Basically if I see a rank 2, it means that my entity went from 1 to 2, and I am counting each rank.  So I mean to say rank2++, rank1-- (because I have 1 less rank1 and 1 more rank2).

Comment: . . As I say, sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: McNets result below produces the desired result--note how rank1 drops when the first rank2 appears--although, he doubles the needed columns.   My actual data is repeat customers: When they purchase a second time I note that in a field 'rank' with value 2... so and and so forth to higher ranks (more repeating customers)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Admittedly, this is a poorly formulated question.  The generic question of how to increment multiple variables without instantiating more columns in my select remains unanswered.  My posted answer below is a simple workaround and it may be susceptible to your warning about 'not calling a variable that was modified in the same line'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the logic I was looking for:

```
select 
   if(rank=1,@rank1:=@rank1+1,if(rank=2,@rank1:=@rank1-1,@rank1) rank1, 
   if(rank=2,@rank2:=@rank2+1,if(rank=3,@rank2:=@rank2-1,@rank2) rank2
from my_table;
```

The pattern then continues for higher ranks...